# Meaning of "Double Stripe"

Tags: vocabulary, phrase-meaning

The 2min+ Youtube clip below is from [Wrech-it-Ralph 2012](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1772341/) Disney movie. I did some research but couldn't find meaningful results.

What does "Double Stripe" mean both in this context and in general?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4c4RdKSsMs

She also said:

> Your breath is so bad it made my ears numb.

The breath has nothing to do with ears. So I expect she is playfully teasing him and exaggerating. Or is there is something else I'm missing?

By the way, watch the movie if you haven't done so. I like it! I can't wait for the expected sequel.

---

You may want to use the search feature to look up "Double Stripe"

---

571
00:28:51,496 --> 00:28:52,362
Hello.

572
00:28:53,865 --> 00:28:58,402
Man, you scared me, kid.
Ah, I nearly soiled myself.

573
00:28:58,404 --> 00:29:00,404
What's your name?

574
00:29:00,406 --> 00:29:02,072
Uh... Ralph.
Wreck-it ralph.

575
00:29:02,074 --> 00:29:04,408
You're not from here,
are you?

576
00:29:04,410 --> 00:29:07,411
No, well, yeah. I mean,
not from right in this area.

577
00:29:07,413 --> 00:29:08,779
I'm just doing
some work here.

578
00:29:08,781 --> 00:29:10,280
What kind of work?

579
00:29:10,282 --> 00:29:12,216
Some routine
candy tree trimming.

580
00:29:12,218 --> 00:29:13,484
You probably
want to stand back.

581
00:29:13,486 --> 00:29:16,019
In fact, this whole area

582
00:29:16,021 --> 00:29:17,287
Is technically closed
while we're trimming.

583
00:29:17,289 --> 00:29:19,356
Who's "we"?
Candy tree department.

584
00:29:19,358 --> 00:29:21,091
Oh! Where is
everybody else?

585
00:29:21,093 --> 00:29:22,826
Ah, it's just me today.

586
00:29:22,828 --> 00:29:24,995
So you just meant
like the royal "we"?

587
00:29:24,997 --> 00:29:27,164
Yep. That's right.

588
00:29:27,166 --> 00:29:30,000
Hey, are you a hobo?

589
00:29:30,002 --> 00:29:33,170
No. I'm not a hobo,
but I am busy.

590
00:29:33,172 --> 00:29:35,973
Okay? So you go home.

591
00:29:35,975 --> 00:29:37,941
What's that?
Didn't hear you.

592
00:29:37,943 --> 00:29:39,977
Your breath is so bad
it made my ears numb.

593
00:29:39,979 --> 00:29:41,245
Listen,
I tried to be nice.

594
00:29:41,247 --> 00:29:43,347
(mimicking)
I tried to be nice.

595
00:29:43,349 --> 00:29:44,848
You're mimicking me.
You're mimicking me!

596
00:29:45,984 --> 00:29:47,351
Okay.
Okay.

597
00:29:47,353 --> 00:29:49,953
That is rude, and this
conversation is over.

598
00:29:49,955 --> 00:29:51,121
And this conversation
is over.

599
00:29:53,091 --> 00:29:55,993
Uh, I wouldn't grab that
branch if I were you.

600
00:29:55,995 --> 00:29:57,294
I'm from the candy tree
department, so I know what...

601
00:29:57,296 --> 00:29:58,829
It's a double stripe.

602
00:29:58,831 --> 00:29:59,563
(grunts)

603
00:30:01,132 --> 00:30:04,468
Double stripes break.
Guh-doy!

604
00:30:04,470 --> 00:30:07,304
Why are your hands
so freakishly big?

605
00:30:07,306 --> 00:30:10,040
Uh, I don't know. Why are you
so freakishly annoying?

606
00:30:10,042 --> 00:30:12,810
Why are you
so freakishly...

607
00:30:12,812 --> 00:30:15,179
Sweet mother of monkey milk!
A gold coin!

608
00:30:15,181 --> 00:30:16,847
Don't even think about it.
That is mine.

609
00:30:16,849 --> 00:30:18,582
Race you for it!
Hey!

610
00:30:18,584 --> 00:30:20,951
I don't have to race for it
because it's mine!

611
00:30:20,953 --> 00:30:23,287
Double stripe!
Come back here!

612
00:30:23,289 --> 00:30:25,022
The winner!
Give it back! Give it!

613
00:30:25,024 --> 00:30:25,923
Whoa!

614
00:30:29,060 --> 00:30:30,194
Double stripe.

615
00:30:30,196 --> 00:30:31,028
(screaming)

616
00:30:33,498 --> 00:30:34,832
Thank you!

617
00:30:35,967 --> 00:30:39,269
Wait! Let me talk to you
for one second.

618
00:30:39,271 --> 00:30:41,205
Okay. Here's the thing.

619
00:30:41,207 --> 00:30:42,940
I'm not from
the candy tree department.

620
00:30:42,942 --> 00:30:46,844
Lying to a child.
Shame on you, ralph.

621
00:30:46,846 --> 00:30:49,580
But I wasn't lying about
the medal. That is my medal!

622
00:30:49,582 --> 00:30:52,115
That's why I was climbing
the tree. It's mine!

623
00:30:52,117 --> 00:30:54,117
It's precious to me.

624
00:30:54,119 --> 00:30:56,520
That thing is my ticket
to a better life.

625
00:30:56,522 --> 00:30:58,956
Yeah, well,
now it's my ticket.

626
00:30:58,958 --> 00:31:01,191
What the...
See you, chump!

627
00:31:01,193 --> 00:31:03,460
Come back!
I'll find you!

628
00:31:03,462 --> 00:31:05,229
I will find you!

629
00:31:05,231 --> 00:31:06,230
Double stripe!

630
00:31:06,232 --> 00:31:07,164
(screams)

631
00:31:08,066 --> 00:31:08,966
Nowhere to hide!

Comment: Could you add context to the expression in text, please? The video may become unavailable or someone may not be able to view it.

Comment: It's been done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just means two stripes.

Ralph is hanging on some candies with stripes, candies with one stripe don't break, candies with two stripes do. They said ‘Double stripe!’ when Ralph grabs one of those, and it breaks.

Also, ‘your breath is so bad it made my ears numb’ means what you thought, she's exaggerating.

Comment: Thank you @QOI. I didn't see well and didn't focus well! Actually, it all because English is insanely full of idioms and movies are full of cultural references etc that I default to expecting idioms and turn of phrases!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help :)